# How to resolve java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: gradle, fileutils, takesscreenshot

I have written a simple script to take the screenshot but it is **giving java.io.IOException** **The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect** what's wrong with the code, or is it anything to do with Gradle version

```
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package WDM;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class App {

    public static WebDriver createDriver() {
        // TODO : INITIALIZE WEB DRIVER USING WDM
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        System.out.println("Driver version " + WebDriverManager.chromedriver().getDownloadedDriverVersion());
        System.out.println("Driver path " + WebDriverManager.chromedriver().getDownloadedDriverPath());

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--headless", "--window-size=1920,1200");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        return driver;
    }

    public static void verifySearchBox(WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO: Validate the presence of search box
        driver.get("https://crio-qkart-frontend-qa.vercel.app/");
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".css-11zsshc"));
        if (!searchBox.isDisplayed()) {
            System.out.println("The search box is not visible");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Verified Search Box successfully");
        }

    }

    public static void takeScreenshot(WebDriver driver, String screenshotType, String description) {
        try {
            File theDir = new File("/screenshots");
            if (!theDir.exists()) {
                theDir.mkdirs();
            }

            String timestamp = String.valueOf(java.time.LocalDateTime.now());
            String fileName = String.format("screenshot_%s_%s_%s.png", timestamp, screenshotType, description);

            TakesScreenshot scrShot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver);
            File SrcFile = scrShot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

            File DestFile = new File("screenshots/" + fileName);
            FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile, DestFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void launchQkartTakeScrnShot(WebDriver driver) {
        driver.get("https://crio-qkart-frontend-qa.vercel.app/");
        takeScreenshot(driver, "QKART Home Page", "Screenshot Of QKART Hom");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = createDriver();
        try {
            // verifySearchBox(driver);
            launchQkartTakeScrnShot(driver);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception Occured " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

This code creates a screenshot folder but not creating a file inside it.

[image]

Comment: If you running on Windows, there is a list of invalid characters for filename in WIndows described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names. 
I believed there are characters ':' inside the `timestamp` variable, you could bypass this by either replace ':' with "-" or convert timestamp to int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string timestamp contains the character **":"** which is forbidden in windows, so while using the timestamps for naming a file always replace the **":"** character with some other valid char. [reffer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1976050/13337068)